# Flutter, firebase. I want to show my registration form data other than the email and password and connect to a unique uid

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Register Screen On Pressed method given, I believe there is a problem with calling Firebase user = result.user

```
onPressed: () async {
 if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
 setState(() => loading = true);
 dynamic result = await _auth.registerWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
 FirebaseUser user = result.user;
 await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).newUserInfo(
 _nameC.text,
 _cityC.text,
 _contactnoC.toString()
 );
if(result == null) {
  setState(() {
    error = 'Please supply a valid email';
    loading = false;
  });
}}},
```

// Database backend

```
class DatabaseService {
final String uid;
DatabaseService ({this.uid});
final CollectionReference userdata2 = Firestore.instance.collection('UserData');
Future newUserInfo(String name, String city, String contactno) async {
  return await userdata2.document(uid).setData({
    'name' : name,
    'city' : city,
    'contactno' : contactno
  });
}}
```

// authentication backend
// register with email and password

```
Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
try {
  AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
  FirebaseUser user = result.user;
  DatabaseService(uid: user.uid);
  return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
} catch (error) {
  print(error.toString());
  return null;
} }
```

// user.dart

```
class User {
    final String uid;
    User({this.uid});
}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO! I need to ask some question to clarify. What is happening when you run the code? Is there any error massage? and what is `_userFromFirebaseUser`?